# XAMPP phpinfo points to a missing openssl default config

Tags: php, openssl, xampp

I have [xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp) version 3.2.2. phpinfo output invalid path for the default openssl config:

`c:/openssl-1.0.2d-win32/ssl/openssl.cnf`

[image]

The regarded path is not found at all on my system and I don't know how to fix this issue.

I have tried to find any settings in `C:\myXamppInstallation\apache\conf\openssl.cnf` that may fix this issue but I could not find anything. Also, I tried to find it in php.ini but there is nothing.

Comment: then either openssl isn't installed, or is in a different path. you'll have to figure out which it is and fix that.

Comment: @MarcB I think it is in a different path because in another section of the phpinfo `_SERVER["OPENSSL_CONF"] C:/xampp-3/apache/bin/openssl.cnf` and this path is found and `openssl.exe` is found there. However, how could I fix the regarded issue in the phpinfo output.

Comment: a lot o what's in $_SERVER is a mix of apache and php information. could be that apache has the correct path but php's isn't.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww You may be right, but if you have got a look at the [tag:xampp] tag questions, you may notice that the majority of its questions like my question.